# How does instantiating view controllers inside Xib files lead to code that is difficult to comprehend and debug?

Tags: ios

In the introduction to [iOS Programming: the Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773772), the authors say that they always create **view controllers** programmatically, and that instantiating view controllers in Xib files leads to projects that are difficult to comprehend and debug.

What, specifically, makes this problematic? And which difficulties would you encounter?

Are there any specific examples, and how does creating the view controllers in code avoid these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote is at Introduction > Style:

> We will always create view controllers programmatically. Some
>   programmers will instantiate view controllers inside XIB file. We've
>   found this practice leads to projects that are difficult to comprehend
>   and debug.

They talk about instantiation. If you have two view controllers A,B, you can alloc/init B in A's implementation, or you can drop a reference to B in A's XIB. In both cases, B may be defined in a XIB or not (the Big Ranch book advises to use XIBs for complex view controllers btw).

---

Anyway, here is the difference:

```
CitySelectionVC *citySel = [[[CitySelectionVC alloc] initWithCities:self.cities] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:citySel animated:TRUE];
```

vs

```
citySel.cities = self.cities;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:citySel animated:TRUE];
```

First case is a explicit instantiation in code. It tells me:

- The VC is created now.
- It needs the cities to work.

The code in the second block references an outlet instantiated in the XIB. It tells me:

- A VC was instantiated at unknown time, with unknown requirements.
- I'm passing the cities.

I favor the first style because it is more explicit, and gives me control of the lifespan of the object.

In iOS 5 you can use Storyboards to create transitions and pass information between controllers. See Session 309 of WWDC2011.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is [the answer I received from Joe Conway](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=3008#p5837) (one of the book's authors) in the Big Nerd Ranch forum:

> "When a low memory warning occurs, a view controller's view is trashed
>   to free up memory. When that view controller's view needs to go back
>   on the screen, it reloads its XIB file.
>
> If there are controller objects (or really, any non-view objects) in a
>   XIB file, those also get recreated. Not knowing this can put your
>   application into an inconsistent state, because a controller that may
>   have held state (or held references to model objects that held state)
>   will be destroyed.
>
> It could be argued that everyone should know this and take the
>   appropriate action to work around this. However, there are a few
>   problems with that argument: not everyone knows this and even if they
>   do know this, they are forced to open up XIB files to see the
>   controller hierarchy AND read through code. This makes things
>   difficult to maintain."

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, this is less of a black-and-white, right-or-wrong situation, and more a case of personal preference.  It's an old debate, as well - the "real programmers do it in code" argument has been around since mainframe days.

Possible advantages of building view controllers in code:

- all the aspects of the interface are in one place, so you can figure out exactly what's going on by reading through one file.
- it's arguably less complex to create the view, if you regard dragging-and-dropping in a UI builder as complex.
- getting fine-grained pixel-perfect control over the UI can be painful in Interface Builder, especially if you're used to the level of layer and layout control from tools like Photoshop.

The counter view:

- unless you're experienced or just that way inclined, getting a sense of how a visual interface looks and feels is very difficult from code.
- working with end-users and designers on interfaces that are built in code is damn-near impossible.
- sometimes it's just quicker to drag and slap controls and nudge them around until it's right.

Ultimately, it's a case of what works for you.  I tend to do it both ways, depending on how complex the interface is, how quickly it needs to go together, and (frankly) the mood I'm in at the time...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a philosophical question. It's hard for me to imaging getting the look and layout correct if it's all in code. On the other hand, using .xib files means that you have no single place to look to make sure all your outlets are actually hooked up.

Localization is IMO going to be much easier with .xib files, too — you can certainly do this with code, but when buttons change size it can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

It's very true that:"real programmers do it in code" but I do not see the problems while debugging until or unless you are not focusing on UI issue while debugging. It means to fix the UI issue you have to fix it through the IB and that issue you should not look into while debugging.

The biggest problem that developers face while doing UI through XIB is developing it in team and putting it in SVN. If you get any conflict and you are required to merge both the code, you have to play through the XML. Sometimes it becomes very tough to resolve the conflict in XIB manually. If you do it by coding you can easily make it done (because you know which line is causing what problem, and what to keep and what to remove).

I hope this will help you to decide on what should you keep in XIB and what you need to do by coding.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from (as others have already pointed out) being a false dichotomy, I find the argument misleading:

While it’s true that you now have two places to look for where things may come from, when you are instantiating view controllers in XIBs, as soon as you need two configurations of the same view controller, you can only lose when you’re heading down the “code only” route.

In my personal experience, most of the code-bloat in the projects I saw or worked on came from a reluctance of separating configuration from functionality, i.e. forcibly “doing it in code” instead of “load a XIB with the configuration”.

In the worst projects, dozens of classes could have been avoided easily by simply treating configuration as data — and leading to better, more robust code because it would have been exercised more thoroughly.

So in my opinion, using XIBs **even to instantiate other view controllers** does not only **not** deteriorate the maintainability of a code-base, but can help a lot in *actually improving it*.

There is one single caveat to using XIBs:
You have to *talk* to each other — there are a few conventions you have to establish within your team, and you have to talk about **who** puts (or is planing to put) **what** exactly **where** and **why**.

Establishing conventions and talking about architecture, however, are the things you should be doing regardless of project or even programming language if you don’t want to end up with a huge maintenance nightmare…

---

A few tips for working with XIBs:

- When writing view controllers, be liberal with asserts — if you have a precondition that something is there, put an `NS(Parameter)Assert` in your viewDidLoad and make sure the exception breakpoint is active, that way you’ll find missing connections easily (including those from code!).
- Give objects meaningful labels, as the auto-generated names can become unhelpful quickly — when your view hierarchy grows in complexity, you won’t see much in your outline when you have a “View” in a “View”-with-seven-siblings-three-levels-deep-in-another-view or have ten UILabels that will be filled with data dynamically.
- Set the editor to perform live autoresizing “Editor > Canvas > Live Autoresizing” most of the time. Only disable it, when you don’t explicitly need it.