# iPhone App Delegate as Hub?

Tags: iphone, methods, delegates

What is the preferred method for inter-class communications? 
If one of my classes needs to access a value that's coming from another class should I use the App Delegate as a sort of Central Hub or is it better to #import them directly?

What's the cleaner/better route to take?

Comment: Related: [passing data in the init](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7791328/412916), using [a singleton as a hub](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7594230/412916), using one of the [storage options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6391408/412916). Sharing data between view controllers has been asked a few times, you'll find more answers through the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use iVars and class methods to achieve what you want, the AppDelegate should not be a boiler for sharing variable between classes. But you can.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve it:

1. Import one class to another and use its methods/properties.
2. Create a global class, initialize it with some values. Access to this class from all another required classes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
3. NSNotification - see [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It allows you to execute some code in your current class when another class execute its own code or fires some action.